# fetching npm registry with angular httpClient causing CORS

Tags: angular, npm, angular-httpclient

I am trying to use angular httpClient to access npm registry to get specific package dependencies

When I am doing the request I am getting CORS error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://registry.npmjs.org/async/2.0.1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. http://registry.npmjs.org/async/2.0.1

```js
this.httpClient.get(requestUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError)).subscribe((result: any) => {
    console.log(result);
});`
```

Do I need to add headers to request in order of this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use unpkg (https://unpkg.com/) instead of https://npmjs.com/

Unpkg is a CDN and allows to use `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: unpkg doesn't contain registry data as far as I know, so this is not related to the question.

Answer (score -1):

If developing locally, you can't change much in your code because npm registry will block anything called from localhost. To make this work, you could use CORS proxies, for instance https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

So your request url would change to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://registry.npmjs.org/async/2.0.1

and you could change your code to something similar:

```js
if(!environment.production) {
    const corsProxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
    requestUrl = `${corsProxy}${requestUrl}` 
}

this.httpClient.get(requestUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError)).subscribe((result: any) => {
    console.log(result);
});`
```

Comment: this issue here is that npm does not support CORS at all. the `if (!environment.production)` is a little misleading here, because this code will not in production either.